# unordered_map.find() matches on different keys

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, unordered-map

I am learning C++.
I have this method that looks in `std::unordered_map` for  a key, and returns true if the key is found and false if not found.

```
bool BufferContainer::contains(std::string *file_path) {
    EditorBuffer *buf = lookup_buffer(file_path);
    if (buf != NULL)
        return true;
    return false;
}

EditorBuffer* BufferContainer::lookup_buffer(std::string *key) {            
     auto buffer = buffer_map.find(key);
     if (buffer == buffer_map.end())
          return NULL;
     return buffer->second;
}
```

I also have a little code that tests these method. It adds a buffer and then looks if a other string pointer matches.

```
TEST(BufferContainer, NotContainsBuffer) {
    std::string name = "buffer";
    std::string name2 = "buffer2";
    BufferContainer container;

    container.open_buffer(&name);
    EXPECT_FALSE(container.contains(&name2));
}
```

The problem is now, that this test fails. If I create the string on the heap, the test succeeds as expected.

```
TEST(BufferContainer, NotContainsBuffer) {
    std::string *name = new std::string("buffer");
    std::string *name2 = new std::string("buffer2");
    BufferContainer container;

    container.open_buffer(name);
    EXPECT_FALSE(container.contains(name2));
}
```

Is there any solution to this problem or am I doing something wrong?
Maybe I should store the actual strings as keys but it seems to me that it would be a lot of overhead.

Edit: I`m aware that I compare addresses and I was not able to recreate this problem in a minimal working example.

Here is the complete "program". 
The test is in `test/testeditor/test_buffer_container.cpp`.
The code for the container is in `libeditor/buffer_container.cpp`.
https://github.com/FlexW/tedit

Comment: We're going to need a [mcve] in order to be able to help you.  On the other hand If you learn how to use a debugger to step through your code, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Why are you using pointers to `std::string` everywhere? You're probably ending up comparing pointers when you're trying to compare the string contents... Needs a design rethink.

Comment: I use it since I am not planing to compare the content of the strings. I am aware of that. I've created a minimal complete example to execute, but was not able to reproduce it..

Comment: So you want to compare addresses?

Comment: @manni66 exactly

Comment: Looks like a really bad idea. I don't think that you show the real code.

Comment: Provide code in a github repo. Think is to much to post all. The most important things are posted. I was able to reproduce the error on a different computer. But the error occurs not if I calling the methods in the main function, only in the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BufferContainer` uses a global variable for its map, not associated with a particular `BufferContainer` instance. Entries inserted by one test are visible in another. That global map is stuffed full of dangling pointers.

It just so happens that `name2` in `NotContainsBuffer` test is falling on the same stack location as a string inserted into the map by some prior test.